# Use a texture and a color on a cube three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, textures

I would like to create a cube that has a texture and a color on it in three.js at the same time.

I want to change the color when the cube is selected. That's why it needs a color.

Will a black and white texture with a color on top allow me to change the color of the texture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color of a material has always an effect on the appearance of the object even there is an texture on it. The default color value is white and the texture looks just normal. But if you set the color to red, the texture will turn reddish (e.g. if you have a black/white texture, you will get a black/red texture).

```js
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();  // default color is 0xffffff
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load('texture.jpg',
    function ( texture ) {
        material.map: texture;
    });

// onclick: set color
material.color.set(0xff0000);
```

Comment: You said "if you set the color to red, the texture will turn reddish" - is it possible to get fully red texture after applying red color?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "get fully red texture"? Do want to (e.g.) download the transformed (black/red) texture?

Comment: I mean to mate texture red without black color

Comment: As far as I know, it only tints the texture with the color, i.e. brighter colors are more affected than darker ones, white gets red, black remains black. In the shader, the colors are multiplied (if I'm not wrong): red 0xff0000 * white 0xffffff = red 0xff0000, red 0xff0000 * black 0x000000 = black 0x000000. You may need some custom shader that meets your purpose and combines the color values differently.