# Correlation between diffuse map and color for a material in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

In the following material:

```
var mat = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({'color': ..., 'map': ...});
```

How does color impact the rendered result, in case of setting the color to average pixel value of the map vs setting the color to white vs setting it to black.

Documentation says in case a `.map` is set for a material, the color of the material "modulates" the diffuse map. What exactly does modulation mean here?

Answer (score 2):

This could be found in source code of [standard three.js shaders](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib). In [meshlambert_frag.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshlambert_frag.glsl) there are rows `#include <map_fragment>` and `#include <color_fragment>`. These [ShaderChunk](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk) includes are processed when webgl program compiles.

In [map_fragment.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/map_fragment.glsl) and [color_fragment.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/color_fragment.glsl) I could see, that `diffuseColor` is multiplied by `color` after map color is applied.

Also, Shader Editor extensions for browsers could be used for looking up source code of shaders you run in webgl.

Comment: In other words: e.g. a red color (`color: 0xff0000`) will turn the texture (or `map`) to a reddish one, with a black color you will see just black, and with a white color you will preserve the texture/map in its original state. I've also explained it for this question: [use-a-texture-and-a-color-on-a-cube-three-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427721/use-a-texture-and-a-color-on-a-cube-three-js)