# Threejs How to change the color of a materials texture

Tags: three.js

I have a threejs scene with a simple plane and a loaded black and white png map on the plane's material.  What I would like to do is change the color of the map without effecting any other meshes in the scene.  Are there any ideas on this?  a snippet of my code is blow:

```
                var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(foilWidth, foilHeight);
                var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
                var texloader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                mat.map = texloader.load(modelOptions.foil);
                mat.color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000); // works is the map is not given
                mat.transparent = false;
                mat.needsUpdate = true;
                mat.transparent = true;
                mat.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                mat.depthWrite = true;
                mat.needsUpdate = true;

                let foil = new THREE.Mesh(plane, mat);
                scene.add(foil);
```

Comment: Seems to be a similar question to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427721/use-a-texture-and-a-color-on-a-cube-three-js/39428386#39428386
Does this work for you?

Comment: A very simple approach would be to change the light color, but that will affect other geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - I have tried both approaches by neither provides me with a working solution.  Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: Try `mesh.material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x964B00)` to paint mash's texture into new color